# circular linked list and error in changing objects property in prototype

Tags: javascript, properties, linked-list, prototype

I want to make circular linked list in js. I do this:

```
var node = { // make node
  name: '',
  score: '',
  next: null,
  previous: null
}

function CircularLinkedList(){ // Circular Linked List constructor
  this.head = null;
}

CircularLinkedList.prototype.push = function(name , score){
  var head = this.head,
    current = head,
    previous = head,
    node = {name: name, score: score, previous:null, next:null };


if(!head){ // if link list was empty
    node.previous = node;
    node.next = node;
    this.head = node;       // ****the problem is here**** line 18
}
else{
    while(current && current.next){ // find last element in link list
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    node.next = head;
    node.previous = current;
    head.previous = node;
    current.next = node;
    }
}
```

And in main file I write:

```
var dll = new CircularLinkedList();
dll.push('a',2);
dll.push('b',3);
```

When I run this code in chrome, I see nothing and chrome stay in connecting.
for example if I change line 18 (****the problem is here****) to

```
this.head = "s"
```

The code hasn't problem. what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In circular you don't need to traverse the list when pushing a new item

```js
var CircularList = function(){
  this.push = function (value) {
    var newNode = { value: value };
    if (this.head) {
      newNode.next = this.head;
      newNode.previous = this.head.previous;
      this.head.previous.next = newNode;
      this.head.previous = newNode;
    } else {
      this.head = newNode;
      newNode.next = newNode;
      newNode.previous = newNode;
    }
  };
}

var cl = new CircularList();
cl.push({name: "hello"});
cl.push({name: "good"});
cl.push({name: "sir"});

document.body.innerText = cl.head.value.name + " " + cl.head.next.value.name + " " + cl.head.previous.value.name;
```

Updated as snippet

Comment: how we get the head?? i cant use `myVar.head` it returns null

Comment: thank you. I used ajax that I cant get the head. my problem solved:)